# Expo + Firebase how activate AppCheck

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-app-check

I am building an App with Expo + Firebase sdk and want to implement AppCheck now. How can i implement it into the App? How can I create an AppChestCustomProvider for IOS(DeviceCheck) and Android(Play Integrity)? How do i get the tokenFromServer and expireTimeMillis for both?
Is there maybe a complete different approach to this issue?

```
import { initializeAppCheck, ReCaptchaV3Provider, CustomProvider } from "firebase/app-check"


    const appCheckCustomProvider = new CustomProvider({
     getToken: () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
      // TODO: Logic to exchange proof of authenticity for an App Check token and
      // expiration time.

      // ...

      const appCheckToken = {
        token: tokenFromServer,
        expireTimeMillis: expirationFromServer * 1000
      };

      resolve(appCheckToken);
    });
  }
});

// Pass your reCAPTCHA v3 site key (public key) to activate(). Make sure this
// key is the counterpart to the secret key you set in the Firebase console.
const appCheck = initializeAppCheck(app, {
  provider: appCheckCustomProvider,

  // for web: new ReCaptchaV3Provider('6LdOHjAlAAAAAAuELCh4n53HGv01THoZVFEJTGO5'),
  // Optional argument. If true, the SDK automatically refreshes App Check
  // tokens as needed.
  isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use react-native-firebase in order to use AppCheck with expo. You can find documentation here: https://rnfirebase.io/app-check/usage

An important note with an expo managed flow is you will need to have a custom dev client setup so that you can add the config plugin required for this package. An example of the config plugin you will need to add can be found here: https://rnfirebase.io/app-check/usage

After following those steps you should have a working implementation. Note that for web you will need to use the firebase-js SDK.

Then you can have device specific setup files. So AppCheck.tsx:

```
export function setupAppCheck(_app: FirebaseApp) {
  const appCheckProvider = firebase.appCheck().newReactNativeFirebaseAppCheckProvider()
  appCheckProvider.configure({
    android: {
      provider: __DEV__ ? 'debug' : 'playIntegrity',
      debugToken: 'YOUR_DEBUG_TOKEN',
    },
    apple: {
      provider: __DEV__ ? 'debug' : 'appAttestWithDeviceCheckFallback',
      debugToken: 'YOUR_DEBUG_TOKEN',
    },
  })
  firebase.appCheck().initializeAppCheck({ provider: appCheckProvider, isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true })
}
```

and AppCheck.web.ts

```
export function setupAppCheck(app: FirebaseApp) {
  // This will set the debug token for using AppCheck during development (localhost and dev clients)
  if (__DEV__) {
    //@ts-expect-error
    self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = 'YOUR_DEBUG_TOKEN'
  }
  appCheck = initializeAppCheck(app, {
    provider: new ReCaptchaV3Provider('YOUR_SITE KEY'),
    isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true,
  })
}
```

Let me know if you would like any more information added to this.

Comment: Did you post the wrong link after "An example of the config plugin you will need to add can be found here"? I don't see a config plugin mentioned there